# Heterogenous containers in Rust for a graph

Tags: rust, graph-theory, container-data-type

I am a C++ programmer learning Rust, and one of my main use cases is a graph-based computation engine. In my graph I have store a homogeneous type, and then I derive from this with a more specific type e.g. in C++

```cpp
class BaseNode {
  public:
    BaseNode(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseNode>>& parents);
    virtual ~BaseNode() = default;

    virtual void update(); 
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseNode>>& parents() const;
    ...
};

template<typename T>
class TypedNode<T> : public BaseNode {
  public:
    const T& value() const { return value_; }

    ...
  private:
    T value_;
}
```

The idea is that the graph is traversed and `update()` is called on each node. The node knows what each of its parents "true type" is and so in its `update()` can do something like `static_cast<TypedNode<DataBlob>>(parents()[0])`.

How do I achieve something like this in Rust?

I thought about having a design like this:

```rust
trait BaseNode {
    fn parents(&self) -> &Vec<dyn BaseNode>;
}

trait TypedNode<T>: BaseNode {
    fn value(&self) -> &T;
}
```

But I read that I won't be able to cast the "trait object" from a `BaseNode` into a `TypedNode<T>`. (Or can I do it somehow using `unsafe`?). The other alternative I thought would be to have a struct that stores the data in `Any` and then to cast that, but does that incur some runtime cost?

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423) also applies to the return value here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all node's parents have the same type then you can use that approach:

```
trait BaseNode {
    type Parent: BaseNode;
    fn parents(&self) -> &[Self::Parent];
}

trait TypedNode<P: BaseNode>: BaseNode<Parent = P> {
    type ValueType;
   fn value(&self) -> &Self::ValueType;
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4742d76bd4f4a0e9d453f36540f2217b)

I'm not sure if I understand your question. Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.